# Problem in getting location in android studio

Tags: java, android, locationmanager, geocoder

I tried to get a latitude and longitude and the address of the current location.
When I tried in the emulator it worked..but when I tried to use my smartphone it was not working.
I have added the location permissions in the manifest.
Please help me with a solution.
The emulator I have used is Pixel 4a API 30.
I can't find where I have gone wrong.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView_location = findViewById(R.id.text_location);
    button_location = findViewById(R.id.button_location);
    //Runtime permissions
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        },100);
    }


    button_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //create method
            getLocation();
        }
    });



}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void getLocation() {

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000,5,MainActivity.this);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

        textView_location.setText(address);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```